# How to check whether the executing code is running in either IIS or NUnit?

Tags: c#, .net, iis, nunit

How can I check whether the executing code is running in either IIS or NUnit? The reason I ask is because I want to load a different NHibernate configuration based on whether my site is live or running in NUnit.

```
var configuration = new Configuration();
if (IsRunningOnIIS)
{
    configuration.Configure();
}
else // if (IsRunningInNUnit)
{
    configuration.Configure("hibernate.cfg.test.xml");
}
```

Comment: Your code should not be managing these sorts of issues: http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html

Comment: Even if you get this working this is the wrong approach and is polluting the code base - your really, really need to inject those kinds of dependencies. Read up on dependency injection and IOC as suggested by the previous two comments

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a wrong approach and you should be using dependency injection. But since you asked:

```
Process currentProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
if(currentProcess.ProcessName == "w3wp") {
    // IIS
} else if (currentProcess.ProcessName == "nunit-agent") {
    // NUnit
}
```

or

```
if(HttpContext.Current != null) {
    // IIS
} else {
    // NOT IIS
}
```

You may need to replace 'nunit-agent' with the name of your runner if you using something like Resharper. Ideally though, you would inject Configuration into initialization code on application startup (manually or using DI container). Order [Dependency Injection in .NET](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1935182501) book.

Comment: +1 for answering *how*.  I would use IoC as both the comments on the OP suggest, tho.

Comment: Thanks - don't worry, this is just for temporary, I will use IoC but I am trying to do something real quick.